# The way to install all essentials for Linux Kernel Build

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

Linux Kernel docs says essential packages for Linux Kernel Build.

https://docs.kernel.org/process/bhanges.html

There are many packages to install !

I want to install all at once or by a few procedures.
There are way to do this ?
Or I should install and check version by one and one manually?

Comment: Programs required by the Linux kernel building are normally installed as **packages** via *package manager*, which depends on the Linux distro you use. E.g. for Ubuntu there is a nice wiki which describes all needed packages: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel.

Answer (score 0):

Tsyvarev, thank you !

As you say, some of packages that Linux Kernel  Build needs are already installed.

And usually, distribution Official site explains remain packages to install.

EX. Ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel